# How does SICP intend the (if) forms without their alternative (else) part to work?

Tags: if-statement, scheme, sicp

[Exercise 1.22 of SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%25_thm_1.22) contains the following procedure:

```
(define (start-prime-test n start-time)
  (if (prime? n)
      (report-prime (- (runtime) start-time))))
```

To my eyes, the `if` form has no alternative branch. I can only see `if (test) (consequent)`. Where does SICP introduce this form? `if` is introduced in [Section 1.1.6](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%25_sec_1.1.6) but I see nowhere in that section that covers "`if` without `else`" cases. It is possible that I could guess the intended behavior from the definition of `cond` in that same section, but said section has [a footnote](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#footnote_Temp_26) that shows that the two are different. So how can I tell how SICP intends such `if` forms to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After consulting the index, I discovered two places where it is defined: [Footnote 29](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-22.html#footnote_Temp_391) in Section 3.3 and [Footnote 10](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#footnote_Temp_527) in Section 4.1. Quoting both:

> Observe that the if expression in this procedure has no < alternative > expression. Such a ``one-armed if statement'' is used to decide whether to do something, rather than to select between two expressions. An if expression returns an unspecified value if the predicate is false and there is no < alternative >.

> The value of an if expression when the predicate is false and there is no alternative is unspecified in Scheme; we have chosen here [in The Metacircular Evaluator] to make it false. We will support the use of the variables true and false in expressions to be evaluated by binding them in the global environment. See section 4.1.4.

I admit that I should've thought to consult the Index before consulting Stack Overflow. Clearly, the internet has rotten my brain. However, I hope that there is a better answer to this question than the one that I've given here. "It's defined two chapters after you need it", even if correct, isn't very pleasant.

On the bright side, codybartfast's comments have rightly pointed out that you don't need to understand the procedure described in Exercise 1.22 to solve the question. In fact, having solved it myself, it's clear that I was immensely overthinking it. It can be solved in less than five lines. Furthermore, it has also been pointed out that, although its first few words happen to match the standard for Scheme, the second quote above is largely talking about the implementation that is being built in chapter 4, rather than anything that's expected to be used or understood in the earlier chapters.

Comment: The language specification for Scheme allows both `if <test> <consequent> <alternate>` and `if <test> <consequent>` about the latter it says _"If <test> yields a false value and no <alternate> is specified, then the result of the expression is unspecified."_  I.e., the implementor of the scheme can return whatever they want (it could be `false` or a special `unspecified` value, but it could also be `42` or  a procedure).

Comment: The behaviour described in Chapter 4 is that of a specific scheme implementation, i.e., the metacircular evaluator that is built in that chapter, it is not claiming to describe the behavior of schemes in general.

Comment: It might also be worth observing that the result of the `if` in Ex1.22 is not used.  The procedure is only callled for its side effect - printing.  Chapters 1 and 2 generally avoid procedures with side effects until they are covered in detail in Chapter 3